# Why GitHub Graphql and Yelp GraphQL don't allow multiple orderBy field?

Tags: graphql

Why GitHub Graphql and Yelp GraphQL don't allow multiple orderBy field?

Now

```
repositories(first:3, orderBy: {field: CREATED_AT, direction: DESC}) {
  edges {
    node {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

I want to query like this.

```
repositories(first:3, orderBy: [{field: COMMENT, direction: DESC}, {field: CREATED_AT, direction: DESC}]) {
  edges {
    node {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply because of their GraphQL API doesn't support this as per define in their GraphQL SDL.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
orderBy: {fields: [COMMENT, CREATED_AT], order: [ASC, DESC]}
```