# GraphQL: idiomatic way to accept an ordered list of sort parameters?

Tags: graphql

I'm building a GraphQL API. I'm want to allow users to specify how records should be sorted, using multiple sorts.

#### What should be possible

If I expose the ability to sort `monsters` by `name`, `birthdate`, and `id`, users should be able to get the API to sort by any combination of those, including (in SQL terms):

- `ORDER BY name ASC`
- `ORDER BY name ASC, birthdate DESC, id ASC`
- ... etc

#### What won't work

A single map, like this:

`sorts: [{name: DESC, id: ASC}]`

...would not tell me the order in which the sorts should be applied (maps are unordered).

#### What works OK, but isn't ideal

Currently, I accept a list of maps, like this:

`sorts: [{name: DESC}, {id: ASC}]`

Each map represents an input object, which has fields like `name` and `id`, which are enums with possible values `ASC` and `DESC`. **I expect only one field to be filled per input object**. ~But I don't know a way to enforce that.~

This is awkward because:

- It would be easy for users to typo their sort parameters as a single map
- I can't specify a default (like `ASC` for `id`) without having it added to every input object map

Is there a more idiomatic way of accepting an ordered list of sort parameters?

---

#### Update

I've now added a user-facing explanatory error when there is more than one key per map. With this change, I think this strategy is OK, but I'm still happy to hear of better ways in the future if they arise.

Comment: I see that someone else (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58971399/4376) has suggested `orderBy: {fields: [COMMENT, CREATED_AT], order: [ASC, DESC]}`, but IMO this is more awkward because `fields` and `order` depend on each other, and it's easy to mess up, providing the wrong number or order of the `order` parameters.

Comment: Remember that the problems GraphQL APIs are best at solving might not be the problems SQL servers are best at solving. There is some widespread confusion that "GraphQL should just be a public SQL API", but that road leads to hell. :)

Comment: @conny Point taken. But I'm not trying to give users the ability to do absolutely anything. For sorting, I specify which columns are sortable on each record type. But I don't think it's unreasonable for users to be able to sort by more than one. And surely there are other examples where an ordered list of tuples would be a useful API input.

Comment: If union types on input objects were possible, we might be able to say "sorts is list of `monster_sorts`s, each of which is either a `name_sort` or an `age_sort` or an `id_sort`"

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer is "no".

Long answer: You *can* introspect your types at startup, and generate the schema dynamically according to some made-up convention using custom scalars to represent sorting directive, for example:

```
monsters(sortBy: [name___ASC, birthdate___DESC, id___ASC]) { name }
```

but this is also "just a convention". The "list of maps" ("array of objects") model that you listed a *non-ideal* might be the best option at this point:

```
# the query
monsters( 
  sortBy: [
    {name: asc},
    {birthdate: desc_nulls_last},
    {id: asc}
]
) {
  name
}
```

BUT, irrespective of which way you choose, avoid the temptation of starting hacking these things in manually - your server code will become convoluted due to this *cross-cutting concern*, as will your schema.

Instead, I have seen some GraphQL-to-ORM-bridging libraries make use of [Directives](https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/schema-directives) to control the runtime schema generation ([one example of this](https://github.com/LastDragon-ru/lara-asp-graphql#sortby-directive)). That should be **much** more viable than hand-carving stuff like this.